# Why does Console.Writeline directly work in an extension method but using return doesn't

Tags: c#, console-application, extension-methods

I'm trying to extend C# List to use a Print function. Using Console.WriteLine(a.Print()) only shows partial output but a.Print2() work correctly where in a.Print I'm calling a method with return type string and in a.Print2 I'm calling a function with return value void.

```
using System;
using ExtensionMethods;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class ExtensionClass
    {
        public static int PlusFive(this int input)
        {
            return input + 5;
        }

        static public string Print(this List<int> input)
        {   
            int i;
            string output = "";
            for (i = 0; i <  input.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                output = input[i].ToString() + ", ";
            }
            output += input[i].ToString();


            return output;
            // Outputs 2, 3
        }

        static public void Print2(this List<int> input)
        {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < input.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(input[i].ToString() + ", ");
            }

            Console.Write(input[i].ToString());
            // Outputs 1, 2 ,3

        }
    }

}
namespace LearningCSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> a = new List<int>(){1, 2, 3};
            // int b = 2;
            Console.WriteLine(a.Print());
            a.Print2();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't even know static public void is legal syntax until I read this.

Comment: When you debugged did that not show you the exact problem with your Print method (overwriting output in your loop)? I mean, I assume before asking here you looked at how the output variable was being constructed in your method? I mean, you wouldn't ask the question without doing very basic debugging first, would you?

Comment: @Chris Why wouldn't you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your `Print()` method is broken. In the loop you always set `output` to a new string. You're missing the plus:

```
 static public string Print(this List<int> input)
 {   
     int i;
     string output = "";
     for (i = 0; i <  input.Count - 1; i++)
     {
         // missing plus here
         output += input[i].ToString() + ", ";
     }
     return output;
  }
```

Note however that there are better possibilites to concat strings. One solution here could be:

```
 static public string Print(this List<int> input)
 {   
     return string.Join(", ", input);
 }
```

Comment: Rene is right.  I'd suggest also spending some time in the debugger.  Setting some breakpoints and examining the value of output in the debugger would likely have led you to the answer very quickly without the need to ask on StackOverflow.  This forum is a great resource - especially for the hard problems - but shouldn't replace good old fashioned debugging, testing, and reading of docs